# turn categorical data to numeric and save to libsvm format python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, libsvm

I have a DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
    A         B        C        D
1   String1   String2  String3  String4
2   String2   String3  String4  String5
3   String3   String4  String5  String6
.........................................
```

My goal is to turn this DataFrame to a libSVM format.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
dummy= pd.get_dummies(dataframe)
dummy.to_csv('dataframe.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

is there a way to turn the dataframe or the csv file to this format. Or is there a smarter way to do the transformation?

I tried loading the script that's meant to do [this](https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug/blob/master/README.md) from this repository as follows:

```
%load libsvm2csv.py
```

and the script is loaded correctly, but when I run:

```
libsvm2csv.py dataframe.csv dataframe.data 0 True
```

or

```
libsvm2csv.py dataframe.csv dataframe.txt 0 True
```

I get `"SyntaxError: invalid syntax"` pointing at dataframe.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After preprocessing your data, you can extract a matrix and use scikit-learns [dump_svmlight_file](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file.html#sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file) to create this format.

#### Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import dump_svmlight_file

dummy = pd.get_dummies(dataframe)
mat = dummy.as_matrix()
dump_svmlight_file(mat, y, 'svm-output.libsvm')  # where is your y?
```

#### Remarks / Alternative:

You are mentioning **libsvm2csv.py** to do this conversion, but it's just the wrong direction. It is **libsvm-format -> csv**.

Check phraugs **csv2libsvm.py** if you want to convert from **cvs -> libsvm** (without scikit-learn).

*I prefer the usage of scikit-learn (compared to phraug)*

Comment: Thanks @sascha my y value should be the target but after I have applied the transformations I have more than 50 columns and none of them can be set as a target. In the dataframe that I have mentioned in my question, target is the last column.

Comment: @Kratos Then you are doing the preprocessing incorrectly. Extract and remove the target Y first, then build the dummies on the X part only. What's the problem. It's very basic stuff. And also: why not use scikit-learn which wraps libsvm nicely (no need to call it manually)?

Comment: it's my first time into this, and I can't find any source to get information of how am I supposed to do it correctly. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Kratos Just use scikit-learn. Extract the last column = target as Y and do your preprocessing on X. Scikit-learn will be able to process Y as it is (strings or whatever). Call SVM within scikit-learn which will use libsvm. The docs of scikit-learn are top-notch with many tutorials and examples. Viel erfolg :-)